# Any way to share AWS resources from one AWS Organization to other AWS Organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I am aware that we can use [AWS RAM](https://aws.amazon.com/ram/) (Resource Access Manager) for sharing AWS resources (via subnet sharing) to other AWS accounts within the same AWS Organization.

However, Can AWS resources be shared with other AWS accounts which are in other AWS Organizations? How?

The use case arises due to company acquisition when producer applications are in the AWS account which is in Organization (say Org-A), and consumer applications are in another account in a different Organization (say Org-B), and by sharing we may reduce the cost of massive data transfer.

Comment: any answers found ?

Comment: no proper solution, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you need service-level integration, [AWS PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/what-is-privatelink.html) might help